# Performance implications of using multiple AnalyserNodes

Tags: web-audio-api

Assume an application has a single sourceNode and many distinct visual components that each require an analyserNode, of varying fftSizes, to operate on that sourceNode.

Should the application create only 1 global analyserNode instance and share it between all the visual components? This would require that each visual component will need to set the fftSize property on the analyserNode each time before it calls getByteFrequencyData() or equivalent.

Or would it be better for each visual component to create its own analyserNode instance, with its own fftSize, and attach it to the sourceNode.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really resetting fftsize each time, I think it doesn't matter much.

Comment: I have been testing this on Chrome. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Having several visualizer components sharing the same analyser, setting the desired fftsize each time before taking a data sample, they seem to be clashing with each other. I think having separate analyser instances and keeping the fftsizes static is the only way to go.

Comment: Would this work better if you set `smoothingTimeConstant` to 0 instead of the default of 0.8?  (Hmm. I don't think the spec explains what happens to smoothing if you change the `fftSize`.)

Comment: That could help, but would that not be detrimental to the aesthetics of my visualizations? I have since done some redesign and creating many independent analyser nodes (up to several dozen) is not a problem for me. I make sure to disconnect them from my audio graph when they are no longer needed.

Comment: The analyser already applies a window function, so the spectrum is already smoothed.  And the smoothing factor is applied across calls, so that's kind of messy already.  The cost of an analyser node is fairly low; it just needs to buffer data until you ask for the FFT results.